# Integration with Redis and Prometheus

Tags: redis, apache-kafka, prometheus

I want to read the metrics off of kafka topic and expose the metrics using http endpoint so that prometheus can scrape the data.

How do i expose the custom metrics using Redis Cache? I need to listen to the kafka topic and expose the metrics using redis.

what is the best way to achieve this? we use java to read metrics from kafka topic.

Comment: I'm confused why Prometheus is needed? If the metrics are in Kafka, why can't you consume from there and into Redis?

Comment: Did you consider Redistimeseries? It was designed to keep monitoring data and has integration with Prometheus https://github.com/RedisTimeSeries/prometheus-redistimeseries-adapter

Comment: metrics in kafka are raw metrics collected from different sources. prom is used for querying data and providing visualization in grafana.

Comment: my question is how can prometheus scrape data from redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape metrics from Redis you need data exporter for example [redis_exporter](https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter)

With data exporter, you have to setup `ServiceMonitor` and `Service` to point to your metrics endpoints.

Comment: Thanks You. I was exploring this redis exporter, Is there a Redis Exporter available which is written in java?

Comment: I don't think so, exporters are a usually small program written in go. I guess it should be easy to modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Thank You. I will look into the program.